# Magit what's the equivalent for `git checkout -b` command?

Tags: magit

What I'm trying to do:

I'm in `develop` branch and would like to create a new feature branch. In command line I usually just run `git checkout -b new-feature-name`.

How can I do it using Magit shortcuts?

Checkout `branch`/`new branch`/`new spin-off`/`new spin-out` just seems a bit confusing. Not sure which one to choose for the task:

[image: magit checkout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried one by one until I found what I was looking for:

`s   new spin-off`

How to verify it: `(magit-process-buffer)` and notice something like the following line at the bottom:

`git ... checkout -b new-feature-name develop`